# Macro to order columns in Excel Tables

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I would like to reorder all the columns from several tables (Set as Table in Excel) one below the other adressed in the same Worksheet.

This is an example so you can have a better understanding of what I currently have:

Table1

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

Table2

```
Col1  Col4  Col5  Col3  Col2
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

Table3 (In this table, I have an extra column which I do not need)

```
Col3  Col1  Col2  Col5  Col4  Col6
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

Desired Result

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
Data  Data  Data  Data  Data
```

My first solution was creating a Macro in Excel but I'm stacked with the code as I'm not an expert. The idea is to create an Array and order the columns for each table.

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim arrColOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer

arrColOrder = Array("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5")

For ndx = LBound(arrColOrder) To UBound(arrColOrder)
  For Each WS In Worksheets
    For Each tbl In WS.ListObjects
```

That is the beggining of the code but I don't really know how to define the Array for each Table.

Answer (score 0):

Considering **Table2** to be in **Sheet1** and **Sheet2** to be a blank sheet in the same workbook, below is the code which will Sort columns left to right:(Table name has to be passed while calling **pSortLeftToRight** sub-routine)

Sub MainCode()

```
'Call Sort Left to Right routine
Call pSortLeftToRight("Table2") 'Need to pass Table Name here
```

End Sub

Sub pSortLeftToRight(strTableName As String)

```
Dim tblSource           As ListObject
Dim varTempData         As Variant
Dim rngDataRange        As Range

'Assign Table data to variant
varTempData = Sheet1.ListObjects(strTableName).Range


With Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Clear
    .Resize(UBound(varTempData, 2), UBound(varTempData, 1)) = Application.Transpose(varTempData)
    Set rngDataRange = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rngDataRange.Sort key1:=rngDataRange.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
End With

varTempData = Empty
varTempData = Application.Transpose(rngDataRange)
Set rngDataRange = Sheet1.ListObjects(strTableName).Range
Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2").Range = varTempData
Sheet1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngDataRange, , xlYes).Name = strTableName

Set rngDataRange = Nothing
```

End Sub